# Canvas Returning As Undefined When Trying To Access In Event Handeler

Tags: javascript, dom-events, typeerror

I do not know why but when I am trying to access a canvas in an event handler it returns as undefined.
My code:

```
var example = function(){

    this.canvas = wind.document.createElement("canvas");
    this.canvas.height = wind.innerHeight;
    this.canvas.width =  wind.innerWidth;

    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
        this.canvas.height = wind.innerHeight; // Error here saying canvas is undefined
        this.canvas.width =  wind.innerWidth;
    }, false);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event handler is called in a different context than the function `example`, so the value of `this` will be different (and `this.canvas` will not exist).

To refer to the original canvas simply save it in a variable and use a closure:

```
var cv = this.canvas = wind.document.createElement("canvas");
cv.height = wind.innerHeight;
cv.width =  wind.innerWidth;

document.body.appendChild(cv);

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    cv.height = wind.innerHeight;
    cv.width =  wind.innerWidth;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in a quick simple web page.  Loaded your code at the bottom  by the  ending tag, changed anywhere I saw wind to window. It got the following:

1) In the browser console(F12 in most browsers) by typing example(); 
undefined  //Is returned
2) Typing canvas; it returns this: canvas height="522" width="911"
//width changes depending on if I shrink or expand my window size.

Explanation:
I put that code block at the bottom so everything else gets loaded in the Document Object Model (DOM).  Then I call the function in the browser console (step 1) and it returns undefined (not necessarily a bad thing.  For instance in Ruby when you create a function in IRB it returns Nil.).  In this case undefined it telling you that the function example was created successfully some time in the past and called into action in step 1.
There are several ways to call functions, but if you don't call it; it will just sit there and do nothing in this case.